# including a file inside a function

Tags: php, function, templates, include

I have a function called `get_header()` which includes the header file in a template (a bit like wordpress), which is working. Also defined in my functions file is a `stylesheetURL()` function which gets the template's stylesheet url.

Inside my header.php file (in a subdirectory "design"), i'm calling stylesheetURL and PHP says it's undefined.

This is the structure:

pagehandler.php - handles page requests. Includes 'load.php' and then 'design/page.php'

load.php - includes 'functions.php' and classes.

functions.php - contains procedural functions like get_header and stylesheetURL. get_header actually includes the header.php file as an absolute url (http://website.com/design/header.php) inside the function, but because functions don't have scope, it should still call the stylesheeturl function fine.

page.php - calls function `get_header()`, echos content, then calls `get_footer()`.

header.php - calls `stylesheetURL()`. << This is where it breaks. The header file is included fine, but doesn't have access to any of the functions.

Why is this happening?

EDIT: 
// settings is a global array, and siteURL displays the url just fine if called from any file other than header.php or footer.php.

```
    function siteURL() {
    global $settings;
    return $settings['site_url'];
}

function designURL() {
    $siteurl = siteURL();
    return $siteurl.'/design';
}

function stylesheetURL() {
    $durl = designURL();
    return $durl.'/style.css';
}

function get_header() {
    $durl = designURL();
    require $durl.'/header.php';
}
```

In fact, if I change from `get_header()` to `include 'header.php'` it works as expected.

Comment: A lot of details in your question, but not the ones we will need to help fix this. Paste the functions.php file for us or make sure the functions.php file is included in the right place so it can be accessed from the "bad page"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is because, you can't require files via an url. You need a path, not an url to require a file. Include is working if you have remote file inclusion set on in your php.ini.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Cheers man, I just used a constant that I defined as a root path instead of using the siteURL function to prepend the header and footer includes. All is working. God dammit! It's always the little things